# Selenium not finidng element id

Tags: java, selenium

I've just begun using selenium web-driver. I'm trying to use it login and navigate/scrape.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

    java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit").setLevel(java.util.logging.Level.OFF);
    java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("org.apache.http").setLevel(java.util.logging.Level.OFF);

    WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver(BrowserVersion.CHROME);


    driver.get("my_Site_I_Reference");

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 4000);

    WebElement name = driver.findElement(By.id("LoginUsername"));

    name.sendKeys("exampleName");

    name.submit();

    System.out.println("Page title is: " + driver.getTitle());
    driver.quit();
}
```

I'm using the code above to try and enter a username into the username field but I am constantly met with this error:

"org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element with ID: LoginUsername"

I'm almost certain the element is called LoginUsername as shown in the picture: [image]

Any help would be very much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: use the wait instead of driver.findElement `WebElement name = wait.until(ExpectedCondtions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("LoginUsername"))`

Comment: do me a favor.. after `driver.get()`, do a `System.out.println(driver.getTitle())` I don't think you are on the page you think you are

Comment: `new WebDriverWait(driver, 4000);` this is 4000 seconds, btw. I don't think you meant that? :) [WebDriverWait](https://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWait.htm)

Comment: Make sure your element is actually displayed. Do something like

Comment: .size to check if the element is inside your DOM, then .isDisplayed to make sure it's actually present on the screen.

Comment: Can you please share HTML code in detail ? You can also give a try by changing it to below                                                       WebElement name = driver.findElement(By.xpath(“//*[@id="LoginUsername"]”));       OR        WebElement name = driver.findElement(By.xpath(“//input[@id="LoginUsername"]”));

Answer (score 0):

It would be still a guess, but I suspect the element is inside an `iframe`. If this is the case, *switch to the `iframe`* before looking for the element:

```
driver.switchTo().frame("frame_id_or_name"); 
WebElement name = driver.findElement(By.id("LoginUsername"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please share HTML code in detail ? Meanwhile, You can also give a try by changing it to below and share what do you see?

```
WebElement name = driver.findElement(By.xpath(“//*[@id="LoginUsername"]”));
```

OR

```
WebElement name = driver.findElement(By.xpath(“//input[@id="LoginUsername"]”));
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that I had Javascript disabled by default I found this out by printing the page source my code loaded

```
((HtmlUnitDriver) driver).setJavascriptEnabled(true);
```

Once enabled selenium behaved like I expected

Comment: It's worth noting that the default WebDriver browser HtmlUnit absolutely hates javascript. If you go to needing to test more javascript oriented pages/application you should probably move to using phantomjs with ghostdriver. You'll avoid a lot of silly errors caused by HtmlUnits engine.

Comment: Thank you for this comment :)!